# Using jquery.load() with jekyll

Tags: jquery, jekyll

**jekyll layout:**

```
<a href="" id="link">ClickMe</a>
<div id="main">
    {{ content }}
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    $("#link").click( function() {

        var url = "about/index.html";
        $("#main").html("<p>loading...</p>").load(url);

    });
});
</script>
```

**about/index.html:**

```
<div>
    <h1>Testing</h1>
</div>
```

When the link is clicked, the #main div shows the "loading" text for a second, but then returns to showing the content it had previously. As I understood it, $.load() should replace the contents with "about/index.html". I know I'm mistaken but can't figure out where exactly. I've tried moving about/index.html to many different locations to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do the request and response look like in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: Actually, I don't see it at all. In Firefox's web developer, under network, it appears to be reloading the entire page.

Comment: Try giving your `a` an `href` of `#`, and changing the following: `$("#link").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); /* rest of the code */ });`

Comment: You sir, are magic. Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

From Jason P:

> Try giving your a an href of #, and changing the following:

```
$("#link").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    /* rest of the code */ 
});
```

Solved. Thanks!